# R: lmer() Error message: unused argument (family = "binomial")

Tags: r, statistics, lme4

I am trying to create a generalised linear mixed effects model using lmer(). However, I get the below error message and, as I am relatively new to stats and lme4, don't understand why or how I can solve this issue.

```
nurse.glmer <- lmer(z1.bk ~ phoneme + gender + age + (1|file), data = nurse, family = "binomial")

Error in lmer(z1.bk ~ phoneme + gender + age + (1 | file), data = nurse,  : 
  unused argument (family = binomial)
```

If it is relevant/helps: z1.bk is just some normalised measuring data in form of floats, phoneme is divided in 3 categories (Er/Ir/Vr), gender is just male and female, and age, well, is age in form of integers.

Comment: This is a bit puzzling.  Binomial GLMMs can only be used on data that are integer numbers of successes out of a defined total, e.g. "3 successes out of 10 trials" (or in a special case, binary (0/1) data).  Can you tell us more about what `z1.bk` is and why you want to fit it as binomial?

Comment: z1.bk are formant measurements that were taken in Hertz then converted into a unit called Bark and then normalised. So I have ca. 600 tokens each belonging to one of the 3 phoneme categories and for each token z1.bk is the formant 1 value at a specific time. I want to know, if phoneme, gender, age and file (which is basically the individual) have an effect on the F1 value. My supervisor wants me use it and referred me to a paper (Tagliamonte; Baayen (2012)) where they suggest to use it together with random forests to analyse linguistic data. They use a similar code, but use treatment coding.

Comment: However, they too have variables, such as 'words' with far more than 2 categories.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any reason you would want to treat this as a binomial GLMM ... ??  Tagliamonte and Baayen (2012) have a binary response variable (*was* vs. *were*), which is why they use a binomial model.  You have a continuous response. Just delete the `family="binomial"` argument.

PS it may be a good idea to do more background reading on mixed models (Baayen has written a lot); in particular

- you may want to consider interactions among the fixed effects
- if each `file` includes observations for more than one phoneme, you may want to use `(phoneme|file)` as your random effect (a random 'slopes' model, more or less)